# How to draw rectangle by coordinates of click?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have pictureBox click event. I get coordinates of click and try t draw circle:

```
  private void pictureMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

    MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e;

    Point coordinates = me.Location;
    int x = coordinates.X;
    int y = coordinates.Y;

    // Create pen.
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);

    // Create rectangle for ellipse.
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 50);

    g.DrawEllipse(blackPen, rect);

    }
```

But it draws circle not in coordinates(x,y) of picturebox. It places circle in another place.

Comment: `DrawEllipse` indeed draws an ellipse, not surprisingly, sitting inside a bounding rectangle. If you want to draw a Rectangle centered around the click location use `g.DrawRectangle (blackPen, x- w/2, y - w/2, w, w);`where `int w = 50;` - Other issues;: >> Where does the g come from? a cached Graphics object? Bad, bad, bad. >> To directly access the Location code the MouseClick event! ; >> if you create a Pen Dispose of it or else you leak gdi resources!
`

Comment: Can you design this as answer with code?

Comment: No, this is really neither clear enough to know what you really want (shall the rectangle persist? Then draw ONLY in the Paint event) - Nor is is worth an answer.

Comment: Yes, I get `g` from  `using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))`

Comment: That is fine then! This Graphics object will be always valid, as long as the image lives. The (very common) newbie mistake is to use a Graphics g = someControlCreateGraphics) object to draw onto a control, which will not really work, unless for a few uses, like measuring or drawing rubber-band graphics. In your case all you need is change the draw method like I showed and do a blackPen.Dispose() or, better, put it in  a using clause..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point ellipseCenter = ((MouseEventArgs) e).Location;
    Size  ellipseSize   = new Size (50, 50);

    Point rectPosition = new Point (ellipseCenter.X - ellipseSize.Width / 2, ellipseCenter.Y - ellipseSize.Height / 2);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle (rectPosition, ellipseSize);

    using (Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage (pictureBox1.Image))
    {
        grp.DrawEllipse (Pens.Red, rect);
    }

    pictureBox1.Refresh ();
}
```